# Generate C++ style code using LLVM

Tags: llvm, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree

I am looking into making a custom language for fun, mostly to learn how it works, but I am having a bit of trouble with concepts before I dig into code.

I have looked at Kaleidoscope example code and many other online resources, but I am confused on how to do a couple things:

**My Goal** 
Translate my code into C++ code OR directly into a machine code with C++ style AST

**Reason**
Mostly to learn, but it would be great if I get this going well enough I may develop it further.

**What is my Language?**
My language is going to be specific to sql and database creation with emphasis on version control and caching strategies.

**My problem**
I am unsure of how to translate some of the information in my "language" to the C++ equivalent.

**Example:**

```
//An Integer type which is nullable and the default value of null.
int number = nullable;
```

Would translate to something like this...

```
public static sqlInt number = new sqlInt(true, null);
```

The problem I am having is, how would I generate the AST and LLVM code generation to recognize the "nullable" field as a new sqlInt without explicitly writing it out? And this would need to work for more complex types:

**Example 2:**

```
//Create a foreign key which is of type int, points to pkID
//forces reference and holds ZeroToMany records for a single pkID
//It is also nullable with a default value of 0.
FK<int>(tableName.pkID, true, ZTM) fk1 = nullable(0);
```

Would translate to something like this:

```
public static FK<sqlInt> fk1 = new FK<sqlInt>(tableName.pkID, true, 
                                              ZTM, true, 0);
```

The question remains, would I have to build the AST special? if so what would I have to do to make this possible? Or would this be specific to LLVM?

I can't seem to find an example of a llvm language similar to this style.

I don't have any actual code as of now, I am simply gathering information and I can't seem to figure this part out from the code I have looked at.

**Edit**
I understand (mostly) how to make a parser and lexer to find the function and assign it to a variable, but I am unsure when I should derive the function to declare the sqlInt and how to find the correct params...etc. Is this during the code-generation after the LLVM IR? should I account for this before the LLVM IR?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using LLVM you're going to want to translate from your language to LLVM IR rather than to the c++ ast.

The process of going from the text of your source language to IR is lexing, parsing, semantic analysis, and lowering.

Comment: While this is informational, I am not really looking for a broad explanation, I have looked at source code for the process you describe above, I am wondering, what would I have to do to make it work like above, what logic in which steps to make it like in my post? I don't need specifics just what I would generally need to do to make it work like I want.

I mostly understand the processes of lexing and parsing but I am unsure of when in this process I would need to account for and what I need to do.

Comment: I think your question is too broad.  To me, your question sounds like "How do I make my programming language work" which is very broad.

Comment: It is a broad question about a specific item, I don't need the whole thing to work, I simply need broad steps describing it, no code or anything. I understand what lexing and parsing does, as well as semantic analysis (less so) but I really need to understand the process of turning a descriptor of a word, into a function. Is this a matter of Symantic analysis or will I handle it in the IR somehow? I get how to parse something as is, that makes sense to me, but at what point would I translate it to the new code like above? That is what I am looking for. Thanks.